# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

In the following code Typescript compiler says property 'doit' does not exist on type 'never'. Could this be a compiler bug?

```
class X {
    public foo(): void {
        if (this instanceof Y) {
        } else {
            this.doit();
        }
    }

    private doit(): void {
    }
}

class Y extends X {
}
```

I found the following workaround:

```
const temp = (this instanceof Y);
if (temp) {
} else {
    this.doit();
}
```

The compiler does not have any issues with this equivalent code, which again leads me to suspect there is a compiler bug here.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems to be a bug: [InstanceOf incorrectly narrow when two type extends same base class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10422).

But, regardless, what is the point of what you're doing?
If you want `foo` to behave differently in instances of `Y` then why not override it in `Y`:

```
class Y extends X {
    public foo(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

And if `doit` is only needed in `Y` instances it should be in `Y`, if it's needed in both it can be protected in `X`.

Comment: It is a hack needed for legacy reasons, i.e., source code of Y cannot be changed.