# 'Property does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

This is similar to [#40796374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796374/property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-never) but that is around types, while I am using interfaces.

Given the code below:

```
interface Foo {
  name: string;
}

function go() {
  let instance: Foo | null = null;
  let mutator = () => {
    instance = {
      name: 'string'
    };  
  };
    
  mutator();
    
  if (instance == null) {
   console.log('Instance is null or undefined');
  } else {
   console.log(instance.name);
  }
}
```

I have an error saying 'Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.

I don't understand how instance could ever be a 'never'.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It's pretty clear from your code that the `else` would indeed **never** get evaluated. The compiler is smart enough to see it.

Comment: This is an example, let me add some more code that shows it still has the issue.

Comment: `It's pretty clear from your code that the else would indeed never get evaluated.` It isn't obvious at all nor there is a smart compiler. There is a dumb transpiler which deviates from the established practices. In C#, for instance, one can assign `null` to any object...

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff, it is established but regrettable practice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History

Comment: This becomes a serious head scratching problem when using with try catch finally variables where they need to be worked on in finally block..

Comment: @rkuksin It's a light practice to deal with Optional in a very low grade  environment.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Because you are assigning `instance` to `null`. The compiler infers that it can never be anything other than `null`. So it assumes that the else block should never be executed so `instance` is typed as `never` in the else block.

Now if you don't declare it as the literal value `null`, and get it by any other means (ex: `let instance: Foo | null = getFoo();`), you will see that `instance` will be `null` inside the if block and `Foo` inside the else block.

Never type documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never

**Edit:**

The issue in the updated example is actually an open issue with the compiler. 
See:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12176

Comment: Thanks @saravana.  I've updated the example with a closure which I would have hoped the compiler would pick up on.  Apologies, I should have added this first.

Comment: Looks like an open issue with the compiler. See the following issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12176

Comment: There is also another issue altogether which produces a similar "wrong" error https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570

Comment: I meet the same issue and resolve it by this: const anotherInstance = instance as Foo // access anotherInstance.name now . And of course, you should put this after the null check.

Answer (score 226):

If you write the component as `React.FC`, and use `useState()`, you can write it like this:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState<any[]>([])
```

Comment: This solved my problem, where I can't assign a type to `arr` as `arr: any`.

Comment: After 17 straight hours of working on an issue today, this was the root problem and the solution. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. I put a lot of time and effort into this error.

Comment: Any reasoning behind why this solves the problem please? Is this just adding extra unnecessary Typescript or is it actually making he code more Type Safe?

Comment: @blue-hope would also love to hear an explanatin.

Comment: In retrospect, from the point of view of the original question, the above example is just casting `instance` to `any` type to get a property called `name` and avoid `never` accessing. The method of avoiding null with ! (bang) or the method of making the compiler not infer the type as null (getFoo)  as answered by other people 
 are also valid.
My solution is as same as
`console.log((instance as any).name)`

Comment: + when assigning state as empty array, the type of state is inferred as `never` cause compiler can't infer with the literal type of array element. so, in this case(assigning empty array), we must give a type hint with `useState` generic parameter like `any[]` or `whatever[]` so that parameter can infer what type of variable can be included in array state.

Comment: sorry for my bad english :( . If you have any further questions, please leave them in the comments and I will be more than happy to comment.

Answer (score 160):

I had the same error and replaced the dot notation with bracket notation to suppress it.

e.g.:

```
obj.name -> obj['name']
```

Comment: is this a bug? worked for me as well. why wouldnt dot notation work?

Comment: @wrod7, yes, this is a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50769

Answer (score 65):

if you're using React `useRef` hook with `TypeScript`, instead of using `any` you can do the following.

```js
const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Comment: You saved my day. For others: if your element is not input, change what's inside <> accordingly, eg. <HTMLDivElement>.

Answer (score 26):

This seems to be similar to this issue: [False "Property does not exist on type 'never'" when changing value inside callback with `strictNullChecks`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12176), which is closed as a duplicate of this issue (discussion): [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

That discussion is pretty long, if you can't find a good solution there you can try this:

```
if (instance == null) {
    console.log('Instance is null or undefined');
} else {
    console.log(instance!.name); // ok now
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitzan.  That's exactly what I'm doing in my code,

Comment: For some situation, I still got the same error, even If I use this method, something like `a!.b!.c`, and told that `Property c ...`.

Comment: Explanation for the '!' operator is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/1393400

Answer (score 12):

In my own case when I was initiating the array. I used:

```
selectedActors: any = [];
```

So it makes it "dynamic" at first

Answer (score 11):

For me the following code is working:

```
const [disc, setDisc] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

What I've seen this far is the following: When you don't specify the type you are passing to the useState() it inferes it is type never.
By make it use the any[] you are able to pass the data when it is requested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

if you're receiving the error in parameter, so keep `any` or `any[]` type of input like below

```
getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option!.name}
```

```
 <Autocomplete
    options={tests}
    getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option!.name}
    ....
  />
```

Comment: In my case, annotating the parameter with `any` worked for me: `this.state.projects.map((project: any, idx) => <Project key={idx} title={project.name}/>)`

Comment: Since this also worked forme, however we're not taking advantage of the Interface resolutions.

Answer (score 9):

For typescript developer using React...
if you use React.useRef() hook
Instead of pre-assign null, declare and use variable type any.

Example:

```
const initialRef: any = null;
const ref = React.useRef(initialRef);
```

Comment: Or `const ref = useRef<any>(null);`

Comment: what is the point of using `any` if you're writing an answer for TypeScript

Answer (score 5):

In your component.ts file just declare the array as the following

```
public arrayName = ([] as any[]);
```

that's worked with me for Angular

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me when I forgot to define a type for the variable.

Answer (score 3):

In React, If you use the UseState in this way, you shouldn't have a problem

```
const [data, setData] = useState<any>([]);
```

In the case of Javascript it works directly because all data types are Any
by default, and this is not the case in Typescript, so you have to let the language know :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (I'm using typescript) I was trying to simulate response with fake data where the data is assigned later on. My first attempt was with:

```
let response = {status: 200, data: []};
```

and later, on the assignment of the fake data it starts complaining that it is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Then I defined the response like follows and it accepted it..

```
let dataArr: MyClass[] = [];
let response = {status: 200, data: dataArr};
```

and assigning of the fake data:

```
response.data = fakeData;
```

Answer (score 1):

in **useState** if u've **never** declared the type :

it assumes it is type is **never** so it shows this error :*"Property does not exist on type 'never'"*

you can type it as :

```
const [datalist, setDataList] = useState<Array<Object>>([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

With React, you can type it as:

const [data, setData] = useState<Array>([]);

Comment: This code is incorrect because `Array` expects a generic...

Answer (score 1):

For `typescript with vue`, if you want to assign a string and null value to a variable then use like this in data field: `employeeType: "" || null` later you can assign null or string to `employeeType` variable

```
export default defineComponent({
 data() {
    return {
        employeeType: "" || null,
    }
.........
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because I had not typed a variable.

So I created the Search interface

```
export interface Search {
  term: string;
  ...
}
```

I changed that

```
searchList = [];
```

for that and it worked

```
searchList: Search[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with ? and !

This piece worked for me.

```js
if (ref != null){
    if (ref.current != null)
        ref.current.appendChild(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the issue with the following expression:

`const node = item ? <a href={item.link}>{item.name}</a> : item.name`

And the else part `item.name` said `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Well this is because if there is nothing inside the `item` object - there can't be a `name` property as well.

So this warning happens when you declare something basically impossible (that's why it's `never`)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the value could be empty initially.
In that case you might want say example

let val = data.notificationId --> here it will throw an error.
So we could simply write
let val = data && data.notificationId

Comment: you can also write this as:  data?.notificationId === data && data.notificationId;   just fyi  =)

Answer (score 0):

My issue disappeared when I DESTRUCTURED my .MAP.

ERROR - Property 'loanId' does not exist on type 'never':

```
    {data?.map((el) => {
        return (
            <div key={el.loanId + el.transactionDate}>{JSON.stringify(el)}</div>
        );
    })}
```

NO ERROR - DESTRUCTURED:

```
    {data?.map((el) => {
        const { loanId, transactionDate } = el;

        return <div key={loanId + transactionDate}>{JSON.stringify(el)}</div>;
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When showing Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. message

selectedMinistryDivision(selectedId) {          
        for( let i = 0; i < this.ministryDivisions.length; i++) {
            if (selectedId == this.ministryDivisions[i].id) {
                return this.ministryDivisions[i];
            }
        }
    }

Solved my problem
selectedMinistryDivision(selectedId) {          
        for( let i = 0; i < this.ministryDivisions.length; i++) {
            if (selectedId == this.ministryDivisions[i]['id']) {
                return this.ministryDivisions[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

I have changed from this.ministryDivisions[i].id to this.ministryDivisions[i]['id']

Answer (score 0):

This example worked for me. Here we are using a simple custom type object (product):

```
export interface ProductType {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export const Product: FC = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductType[]>([]);
```