# how to fix Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339) any in nextjs with google maps

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to read GEOJson data on Google Maps using Nextjs .. am getting the GEOJson file from a URL .. here is my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { subaBaseKey, subaBaseURL } from 'src/pages/enums'
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';


const containerStyle = {
    width: '100',
    height: '400px'
};


export default function CountriesMap() {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null)


    async function fetchTheData() {
        const supabase = createClient(subaBaseURL, subaBaseKey);
        const { data: fetchedCountries } = await supabase.from("countries").select();
        if (fetchedCountries != undefined && fetchedCountries?.length > 0) {
            const publicUrl = supabase.storage.from('uploads').getPublicUrl('geojsons/countries/countries.json')
           
            return publicUrl['data']['publicUrl'];
        } 
    }


    async function createNewInput(fileURL: string) {
        const response = await fetch(fileURL);
        const geojsonData = await response.json();

        if (map) {
            map.data.addGeoJson(geojsonData); //error: Property 'data' does not exist on type never.
            
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTheData().then((fileURL) => {
            createNewInput(fileURL!)
        })
    }, [])



    const googleMapsApiKey = "i have my api key here !! "
    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: googleMapsApiKey
    })


    const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(map)
    }, [])

    const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(null)
    }, [])



    return isLoaded ? (
        <>

            <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                center={{
                    lat: 29.95375640,
                    lng: 31.53700030
                }}
                zoom={4}
                onLoad={onLoad}
                onUnmount={onUnmount}
            >
                { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */}
                <></>
            </GoogleMap>

        </>
    ) : <></>
}
```

am getting the error `//error: Property 'data' does not exist on type never.` from line `map.data.addGeoJson(geojsonData);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Property does not exist on type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147937/property-does-not-exist-on-type-never) Particularly, the accepted answer seems to apply to your case.