# Property 'click' does not exist on type 'never'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

According to other similar issues about this type of error with TypeScript (on questions [#44147937](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147937/property-does-not-exist-on-type-never) and [#40796374](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796374/property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-never)) I've found that assigning `null` to create a state or reference will cause this problem:
`Property ... does not exist on type 'never'`

how to handle this issue in this example component?

```
const FooComponent: FunctionComponent<FooInterface> = () => {

    const myRef = useRef(null)

    const handleClickOnButton = () => myRef?.current?.click();

    return (
       <div>
           <div ref={myRef} />
           <button onClick={handleClickOnButton} />
       </div>
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

TypeScript can't infer the type of the ref from where you use it later in the code, you have to tell it the type of the ref:

```typescript
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(`useRef` adds the `null` type to the type parameter for you if you use `null` as the initializer, so you don't have to use `<HTMLDivElement | null>`, though it's fine if you do and you get the same result.)

Comment: thanks for your explanation but my problem is persisting. 
I'm not using <HTMLDivElement> or any type for defining useRef (see my code snippet on question)

Comment: I've recreated your code and it's working. @novonimo

Comment: @novonimo - You are using a `div`, here: `<div ref={myRef} />`. When I copy your code into a Preact/TypeScript project (`FunctionalComponent` tells me you're using Preact), I get the error you describe. When I add the type as shown in the answer above, the error goes away. Same thing if I do that in a React/TypeScript project and change `FunctionalComponent` to `FunctionComponent`. Perhaps you just didn't add the change correctly?

Comment: I just edit my post and fix the FunctionCompnent. I'm using React and using FunctionComponent type @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @novonimo - No, those errors do not occur with the code in the question amended as shown in the answer. Proof: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-pare-neihr?file=/src/App.tsx